# excel-like JavaScript application regex error: nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript, regex

Could someone help me figure this out, thanks in advance.

I have this regex expression to evaluate the value of the selected "cell" (text input element) in an spreadsheet application.

I'm trying to implement something like Microsoft Excel.

```
function evaluate(){
    var a = document.activeElement;
    var pattern = /^=({|()*[A-Z]+\d+(+|-|*|\/)?(}|))*/g;
    while(a.value.test(pattern)==true){
        var index = pattern.lastIndex;
        document.write(index);
    }
}

try{evaluate();}catch(e){document. Write(e);} //throws exception: nothing to repeat
```

Regex explanation
Expects to begin with an "=".
0 or more occurrences of an opening bracket or parenthese.
One or more Uppercase letters followed by one or more digits.
Expects one or none of either one of a mathematical operator.
Could end with an closing bracket or parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You need escape `*`, `+` , `(`, `)` symbols which are present inside the capturing group.

```
^=({|\()*[A-Z]+\d+(\+|-|\*|\/)?(}|\))*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qI4aA6/2)

And also it's better to use the below regex because the above regex would also matches the string which starts with `=` followed by `{` and  ends with a `)` paranthesis.

```
^(?:=({)*[A-Z]+\d+(\+|-|\*|\/)?(})*|=(\()*[A-Z]+\d+(\+|-|\*|\/)?(\))*)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qI4aA6/3)